# Logout user - Java EE 6 Security

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss

I have one servlet representing secure content, annotated as follows:

```
@WebServlet(name = "GreetingServlet", urlPatterns = {"/greeting"})

@ServletSecurity(
        @HttpConstraint(
            rolesAllowed = {"TutorialUser"} ) )
```

and web.xml as below:

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
  <display-name>hello2_basicauth</display-name>


  <!--other servlet names and mappings are defined via annotations-->


  <security-role>
    <role-name>TutorialUser</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
  </login-config>
</web-app>
```

when I've entered the **/greeting** path for the first time, username/password prompt appeared ( earlier I have created users for Jboss using add_user.sh).
After inputing right credentials I was able to see the secure content offered by the servlet.

The problem now is that whenever I access the **/greeting** path again, I'm no longer asked for the credentials.

I have implemented below logout servlet:

```
    @WebServlet(name = "Logout", urlPatterns = "/logout")
@ServletSecurity(
        @HttpConstraint(
                rolesAllowed = {"TutorialUser"}                 // 403 if user not present ...    // default add user to file realm and assign to TutorialUser group
        )
)
public class Logout extends HttpServlet {

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logout.class.getCanonicalName());

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("---- Principal = " + request.getUserPrincipal());
        request.logout();
        logger.info("---- Principal = " + request.getUserPrincipal());
    }
}
```

however it doesn't work ( I  can still access resource at **/greeting** without logging in).
Console logs this when accessing **/logout**:

```
 INFO  [servlets.Logout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-4) ---- Principal = duke3                                                                                              
 INFO  [servlets.Logout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-4) ---- Principal = null
```

Comment: With BASIC authentication, the browser has most probably cached the credentials.

Comment: Browser request has header:
Authorization:Basic ZHVrZTM6bnVrZW0=
once user is authenticated. In order to see the login prompt again, I have to shut down the entire browser (shutting down tab is not enough). I have no idea why and how to force logout, once user accesses my /logout servlet :/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the way BASIC authentication works. Roughly the sequence is:

- With BASIC authentication, the browser remembers the protected resources and the credentials and sends them back with every request to the protected resource.
- The server creates the session and authorizes the user based onthe session cookie, despite the fact that the credentials get sent again (so the server does not have to look at the database every time, just once per session).
- The logout servlet gets called and *correctly* destroys the session. But, with the next request to the protected resource, the browser sends the credentials and the server transparently logs the user back in! (You can verify that by checking that the session cookie has changed after the logout.)

What can be done?

1. Embrace the way things work, i.e. adapt your logic to BASIC authentication.
2. Use FORM authentication (prettier and works as you seem to expect).

Comment: Thanks @Nikos, before I will try FORM, I want to fully understand how the BASIC works. If I call request.logout(), sessionId stays the same. If I call session.invalidate(), session id will change, and browser will create a cookie (JSESSIONID) that holds the updated sessionId.  I want to know where are the credentials stored in the browser. Cause the JSESSIONID cookie does not seem to have them.

Comment: Unless session cookieactually does store credentials using some smart hashing, eg, while invalidating my session cookie will change like this:
JSESSIONID=vZX-uZXIpGIphsVWzoZWDWrn.undefined
JSESSIONID=obMR2+JOAiXtzDWLXtWAmOhg.undefined

Comment: You are right concerning the `request.logout()` - `session.invalidate()`. I always go for `session.invalidate()` for logging out, or the (logged-out) session will still hold (potentially sensitive) data from the logged-in session. (I mistakenly thought `request.logout()` would do the same). Session cookie DOES NOT normally store any info; it is a random number, used as a key to a *map* in the server that stores session data.

Comment: So are the credentials stored in the browser? I'm not able to find anything besides this single cookie with a sessionID :/

Comment: I *think* e.g. in Firefox you will find the credentials stored in the "Security" tab of "Preferences" under "Saved Passwords" (name depends on version/system, I think). I do not have something to test right now. It may be that the BASIC password is *not* stored persistently, just until the browser is shut down (i.e. in memory). You will find the cookies in the "Cookies" tab of Firebug.

Comment: Follow @NikosParaskevopoulos recommendation on FORM authentication. Do not use BASIC because there is no straight-forward way to implement logout!!! Browsers send the credentials until they are closed. All tabs actually. Pretty weird, I know.

Comment: >`authorizes the user based on the session cookie` - Note that this depends on which authentication mechanism/framework is used. Standard Java EE authentication (JASPIC) does not do this, but for instance the proprietary JBoss security system (based on PicketBox) does indeed do this.