# BASIC authentication does not show up the authentication popup for the constrained resource second time

Tags: authentication, servlets

I am trying the BASIC authentication mechanism. When i try to access the constrained resource second time the popup for username and password does not come up.

Following are the roles and users defined in my tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="Admin"/>  
<role rolename="Member"/>
<role rolename="Guest"/>    
<user username="Annie" password="admin" roles="Admin, Member, Guest"/>    
<user username="Diane" password="coder" roles="Member, Guest"/>    
<user username="Ted" password="newbie" roles="Guest"/>
```

Following are the entries defined in my web.xml

```
<web-app>

<display-name>SecurityApp</display-name>    

<servlet>
<servlet-name>BeerAppServlet</servlet-name>    
<servlet-class>com.example.servlets.BeerAppServlet</servlet-class>    
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>    
<servlet-name>BeerAppServlet</servlet-name>   
<url-pattern>/Beer/AddRecipe</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>    

<security-role> <role-name>Admin</role-name> </security-role>    
<security-role> <role-name>Member</role-name> </security-role>    
<security-role> <role-name>Guest</role-name> </security-role>   

<security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>Update</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/Beer/AddRecipe/*</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>

<auth-constraint>
 <role-name>Admin</role-name>
 <role-name>Member</role-name>
</auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>

<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>

</web-app>
```

My webapp name is SecurityApp. 
For the first time when i access my app as follows
`http://localhost:8083/SecurityApp/Beer/AppRecipe` i get the popup for entering the user name and password and i enter the following credentials username=Diane password=coder. After entering the above credentials the authentication is success.

For the second time when i type this url `http://localhost:8083/SecurityApp/Beer/AppRecipe`. 
I dont get the authentication popup for username and password. Why is it so. can anyone please explain

Answer (score 1):

By using [basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) the credentials are **stored at client side** (your browser).

The web browser takes care of creating a `BASE64`-Encode of username and password and **send it automatically** each time you request to the same page. This means that you are "logged in" immediately without re-entering your credentials.

You can just close and open your browser, to show the username/password dialog again.

Comment: Your answer clears my doubt. One small clarification In BASIC authentication is there a way that the credentials are not stored at the client side and for each request of the constrained resource the username/password dialog opens up ?

Comment: In short: No. There is no logout functionality with basic-auth. You could use a web form/cookie based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Because the browser caches your credentials (username, password) for the page and authentication realm and automatically sends them the next time you visit the page. This is how BASIC authentication works. If you close (all instances of) the browser, it will ask for credentials again, unless it is configured to store them permanently. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025644) related question.