# Tomcat authentication for subsequent access

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, servlets, web-applications

I am trying to simulate how authentication (BASIC) is happening in Tomcat, the issue is when I try to get resource for 2nd time its not asking for the password and directly showing the resource on my browser. How can I force the log in pop-up for every request?

Below is the Servlet code I am using.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//import org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.Base64;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("This is the Test Servlet");

        Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
            out.print("<br/>Header Name: <em>" + headerName);
            String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
            out.print("</em>, Header Value: <em>" + headerValue);
            out.println("</em>");
        }

        out.println("<hr/>");
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("authorization");
        String encodedValue = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
        //out.println("Base64-encoded Authorization Value: <em>" + encodedValue);
        //String decodedValue = Base64.base64Decode(encodedValue);
        //out.println("</em><br/>Base64-decoded Authorization Value: <em>" + decodedValue);
        out.println("</em>");
    }

}
```

and part of my web.xml with roles and users

```
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>   
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" 
roles="tomcat"/>   <user username="myname" password="mypassword" roles="tomcat"/>   <user username="test" password="test"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

PS: I am aware its not the good way of authentication, but I need to know it works then I can explore the ssl authentication.

Comment: check this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015263/basic-authentication-does-not-show-up-the-authentication-popup-for-the-constrain

Comment: Thanks, it answers my queries @Avinash Reddy

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the session after every call (last line of your doGet()-method):

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```